# Code listing stays empty

Tags: listings

I'm trying to add code listings from an external file to a document I'm working on. Unfortunately, in the resulting PDF all I get is the caption and a rectangle with the right width and background color. But it does not have any content.

I'm including my listings like this:

```
\lstset{language=[Objective]C, basicstyle=\footnotesize, showstringspaces=false, tabsize=2}
\lstinputlisting[label=lst:Animation, caption=foo]{Ressourcen/Animation.txt}
```

`lstset` is configured as follows:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.9}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstset{
    float=hbp,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black}\small\smaller,
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},
    stringstyle=\color{colString},
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single,
    extendedchars=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},
    breakautoindent=true
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

*Minimal* example:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, % Schriftgröﬂe
    DIV10, 
    ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
    a4paper, % Papierformat
    oneside, % einseitiges Dokument
    titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
    parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
    headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
    listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben
    draft % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.9}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstset{
    float=hbp,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black}\small\smaller,
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},
    stringstyle=\color{colString},
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single,
    extendedchars=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},
    breakautoindent=true
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=[Objective]C, basicstyle=\footnotesize, showstringspaces=false, tabsize=2}
        \lstinputlisting[label=lst:Animation, caption=foo]{Animation.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: WOuld be usefil with a full minimal example taht we can work with. Working crystal balls are hard to come by these days.

Comment: I added an example. Does it help?

Comment: Also a small excerpt from `Animation.txt` would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the `draft` class option:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, % Schriftgröﬂe
    DIV10, 
    ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
    a4paper, % Papierformat
    oneside, % einseitiges Dokument
    titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
    parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
    headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
    listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben
%   draft % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}
```

The global `draft` option is recognized by the `listings` package and when it is in effect, the package prints no stand alone files, but only shows the captions and defines the corresponding labels.